# When $|f|$ is differentiable at $c$ if $f$ is differentiable at $c$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable then $|f|$ is differentiable at $c$ $\iff$ either $f(c) \neq 0$ or if $f(c)= 0$ then $f^\prime (c) =0$

I have proved the $(\Longleftarrow)$ case, but I cannot prove $(\Longrightarrow)$ case. Please help.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive. Show that, on one side of $c$, $f(x) < 0$ and on the other, $f(x) > 0$ (which side of $c$ depends on the sign of $f'(c)$). So, on one side, $|f(x)| = f(x)$, and on the other $|f(x)| = -f(x)$. Use this to conclude that the left and right derivatives are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

If $|f|$ is differentiable at $c$ and $f(c) = 0$ then $0 = |f|'(c)$
since $|f|$ has a minimum at $x=c$.

It follows that
$$
 \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\right| = \left|\frac{f(x)}{x-c}\right|
= \left|\frac{|f(x)|-|f(c)|}{x-c}\right|
$$
converges to $|f'(c)| = 0$ for $x \to c$.

This shows that $f'(c)$ exists and and is equal to zero.